# Will a Samsung Network Extender work after disconnecting the Ethernet cable?

Tags: ethernet

Is it true that once configured the [Samsung Network Extender from Verizon](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/network-extender-router-configuration/) will work after disconnecting the Ethernet cable?

Comment: [Verizon Samsung Network Extender -- User Manual](http://www.verizonwireless.com/dam/support/pdf/network_extender_user_manual.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that once configured the [Samsung Network Extender from
>   Verizon](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201110/20111001032801200/SCS-26UC4_Network_Extender_1x.pdf) will work after disconnecting the Ethernet cable?

From everything I am reading here, it seems the Ethernet cable needs to always connected. The two [key system requirement are as follows](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201110/20111001032801200/SCS-26UC4_Network_Extender_1x.pdf):

> - An always-on broadband Internet connection with a minimum speed and available bandwidth of 300 kbps.
> - An available Ethernet (LAN) port on either your broadband modem or a router connected to the modem.

Answer (score 1):

If you unplug the Ethernet cable, "you won't be able to use the Network Extender functionality."

http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/network-extender-faqs/

> Q: What happens to my Network Extender if I lose my connection to the
>   Internet?
>
> A: The Network Extender requires an active broadband Internet
>   connection. You won't be able to use Network Extender functionality
>   until your Internet connection is restored. When your Internet
>   connection is restored, the Network Extender will reestablish its
>   connection.